# CSS3 background-size: contain;

Tags: css, background-image

I'm a bit stuck with some of the new CSS3 Background commands an was wondering if anyone could advise?

I'm trying to create a  that has a background image that scales dynamically to the Screen/Browser Size.

here's is an example of the effect I want to achieve, this is running on the < body > tag http://www.css3.info/demos/background-size-contain.html

The problem I am having is that the < body > tag needs no height or width defining, but a < div > does, here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>background-size: contain;</title> 
<style type="text/css"> 

#please_expand {
background-image: url(images/betweengrassandsky.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-color: #EEE;
background-size: contain;
}
</style>

<body>
<div id="please_expand">
    <h1>Example J - background-size: contain;</h1>
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: add height:100% and width:100%

Comment: Before exploring the new CSS3 features, it might be worth learning the basics.

Comment: @bažmegakapa  << thanks, I do know the basics... do you? ... The suggested comment does not work, I have already tried that before posting. 

I'm am trying to get the DIV to behave like the BODY tag and have the background image fill the whole page, dynamically adjusting

Comment: @kie It was not an insult. It was serious. This question (or variations) is asked every second day. It is also covered in a thousand blogs and tutorials.

Comment: @bažmegakapa -- Fair enough, it was the height 100% thing that is the issue as you explained further down the page... now I understand, thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On block elements (like `div`), height does not work the same way as width. If you don't specify a height, the element will be as high as its content. That's one thing.

`height: 100%` would be the way to go if you want your div to be as big as `body` is, but the trick is that [a percentaged height always comes from the parent's height](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-height-property). So you have to set `height: 100%` on all the parents (including `html`) for crosss-browser results.

```
html,body,#please_expand { height: 100%; }
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rrjrz/)

Comment: Thats the ticket.... Just a side note - how come the reset? I dont know too much about height 100% only that it never works (not that I have cause to use it much).

Comment: @kie Added some explanation. `height: 100%` always works, you just have to learn how it works. It always comes from the parent element's height. If it is `auto`, it counts as zero.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand, thats some very useful info

Comment: @kie The last sentence in my previous comment is not 100% accurate. If the parent's height is `auto`, the percentage will return `auto` also, not zero.